# JavaScript: Traversing and Reversing Singly-Linked Lists and Converting Between SLLs and Numbers

Tags: javascript

**INTRO**
Today, while doing a mock interview with a Facebook JavaScript problem, I blanked out on how to handle singly-linked lists.  The code I had so far is simply a function that takes 2 linked lists and returns another linked list.  My plan is below.

**QUESTION**
You are given two non-empty linked lists of arbitrary length representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

*Example:*

> Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4) Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8 Explanation:
>   342 + 465 = 807.

**PLAN**

1. Copy each number from the first linked list into an array in order.
2. Reverse the array.
3. Convert the array to a string then to an integer and store this in a variable.
4. Repeat this for the second linked list.
5. Sum the two numbers and store this value in a variable.
6. Convert this sum into a string.
7. Use Array.from on this string to convert it into an array then reverse the array.
8. ?
9. Return the new linked list.

```
/*
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val)
 * {
 *  this.val = val;
 *  this.next = null;
 * }
 */

/* Expected input and output.
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */

var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2)
{

};
```

Comment: Do you have to do it in place or you have to allocate new space for result list??

Comment: BTW.  Just realized you have not actually asked a question - just jumped to the conclusion you wanted to see how other people might to do it.  Please revise your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create new arrays holding the same data as the linked list. You can process both the lists while iterating on them and creating the result list in same loop. While doing this you have to take care of the carry from the addition.

Basically you have to do like:

```
let currNodeList1 = l1, currNodeList2 = l2;  //assuming that l1 and l2 point to head of linked list 
let resultListHead = null, currNodeResultList = null;  //to store the result
let carry = 0, sum = 0;
while(currNodeList1 != null && currNodeList2 != null) {
    sum = carry + currNodeList1.val + currNodeList2.val;
    carry = Math.trunc(sum / 10);   
    sum = sum % 10;

    let newListNode = new ListNode(sum);
    if(currNodeResultList == null) {
        resultListHead = newListNode;
    } else {
        currNodeResultList.next = newListNode;
    }
    currNodeResultList = newListNode;
    currNodeList1 = currNodeList1.next;
    currNodeList2 = currNodeList2.next;
}

if(currNodeList1 == null) {   //other list is longer in length
    while(currNodeList2 != null) {
         // calculate sum as carry + currNodeList2.val
         //same carry logic and keep appending to the end of the result list
    }
}

if(currNodeList2 == null) {   //other list is longer in length
    while(currNodeList1 != null) {
         //calculate sum as carry + currNodeList2.val
         //same carry logic and keep appending to the end of the result list
    }
}
```

Obviously you can make the code more modular by refactoring the repeating parts but the general idea should be this.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with linked lists, you can easily take a recursive approach. It tends to keep the code simple. For adding two linked lists together all you need to do is the following:

1. Take a node
2. Add the two values together
3. Keep that value in a new node.
4. Move over to the next node and repeat from step 1.

This is the general outline. There are few edgecases to keep track of

- the sum of both numbers is greater than `10` - in that case, you have to carry the extra over to the next sum operation. So, for a sum of `12` you need to only keep `2` and carry `1` over.
- One list is exhausted, but the other still has values - just treat is as having a value of `0` - that will not effect the result. If you try to sum `1` and `0` you'd get `1`, which is the correct thing to have.
- Both lists are exhausted but there is a value carried over - same as above. If you summed lists that were `9` and `3`, then you'd get `2` and the next iteration would have no more lists but a carryover of `1`.

```js
/*
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 */
function ListNode(val)
{
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}

/* Expected input and output.
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2)
{
  return recursivelyAddLists(l1, l2, 0);
};

/* 
 * Recursively add two lists together producing a new list for each digit
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @param {number} carryover 
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
function recursivelyAddLists(l1, l2, carryover)
{
  //you can also safely assume that the carryover is always present. 
  //But adding a default is a good practice
  carryover = carryover || 0;
  
  //if there is nothing to add, we are finished
  if (l1 == null && l2 == null && carryover === 0) return null;
  
  //provide fallback in case at least one or both lists are exhausted
  l1 = l1 || new ListNode(0);
  l2 = l2 || new ListNode(0);
  
  //calculate the sum of both nodes with any potential leftover from previous sums
  var sum = l1.val + l2.val + carryover;
  
  //clamp to only single digit numbers
  var newVal = sum % 10
  
  //the amount to move add with the next nodes
  var newCarryover = Math.floor(sum / 10);
  
  //create the result node
  var newList = new ListNode(newVal);
  
  //recursively determine what the next node is
  newList.next = recursivelyAddLists(l1.next, l2.next, newCarryover);
  
  //finish
  return newList
}


//use the sample data for a test
var input1 = new ListNode(2);
input1.next = new ListNode(4);
input1.next.next = new ListNode(3);

var input2 = new ListNode(5);
input2.next = new ListNode(6);
input2.next.next = new ListNode(4);

console.log(debugPrintList(addTwoNumbers(input1, input2)))


//simple function to recursively collect the content of the list to a string
function debugPrintList(list) {
  if (list.next == null) return list.val;
  return list.val + " -> " + debugPrintList(list.next);
}
```

I have created a new function to do the recursive addition in order to preserve the interface of the first one. The only difference is the `carryover` parameter. However, it's possible to just add the parameter and default it to zero and the thing will still work. However, given it's an interview, they might penalise you for this change. Still, for completeness sake, here is what this would look like:

```js
/*
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 */
function ListNode(val)
{
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}

/* Expected input and output.
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2, carryover) //<- adding the parameter
{
  carryover = carryover || 0;
  
  if (l1 == null && l2 == null && carryover === 0) return null;
  
  l1 = l1 || new ListNode(0);
  l2 = l2 || new ListNode(0);
  
  var sum = l1.val + l2.val + carryover;
  
  var newVal = sum % 10 
  var newCarryover = Math.floor(sum / 10);
  
  var newList = new ListNode(newVal);
  
  //recursively calling this same function
  newList.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next, newCarryover);
  
  return newList
};


//use the sample data for a test
var input1 = new ListNode(2);
input1.next = new ListNode(4);
input1.next.next = new ListNode(3);

var input2 = new ListNode(5);
input2.next = new ListNode(6);
input2.next.next = new ListNode(4);

console.log(debugPrintList(addTwoNumbers(input1, input2)))


//simple function to recursively collect the content of the list to a string
function debugPrintList(list) {
  if (list.next == null) return list.val;
  return list.val + " -> " + debugPrintList(list.next);
}
```

One last note - this solution is using ES5 features only. I've based that on the code given. ES6 will not really have a big impact but the most prominent change would be that you don't need to manually give a default to `carryover` - instead you can simply have `recursivelyAddLists(l1, l2, carryover = 0)`. The other ES6 changes are minor at best - using `let` and `const` instead of `var` and possibly using destructuring to get the value of the node and the next node, so you could do something like

```js
const {val: value1 = 0, next: next1 = null} = l1 || {}
const {val: value2 = 0, next: next2 = null} = l2 || {}
```

However, I personally find that less readable.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do step 8 of your plan is to use the [reduce method of Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Like this:

```
function ListNode(val)
{
   this.val = val;
   this.next = null;
}

const array2List = function(list, nextValue)
{
   let node = new ListNode(parseInt(nextValue));
   node.next = list;

   return node;
}

let numberArray = Array.from('807');

let list = numberArray.reduce(array2List, null);

console.log(list);
```

Or change your plan and do something like:

```
const addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2)
{
   let sumList = new ListNode(0);
   let node    = sumList;
   let carry   = 0;

   while (node)
   {
      let l1Value = (l1) ? parseInt(l1.val) : 0;
      let l2Value = (l2) ? parseInt(l2.val) : 0;

      let sum  = carry + l1Value + l2Value;

      node.val = sum % 10;
      carry    = (sum - node.val)/10;

      if (l1) { l1 = l1.next }
      if (l2) { l2 = l2.next }

      node.next = (l1 || l2 || carry) ? new ListNode(0) : null;
      node      = node.next;
   }

   return sumList;
}
```

Comment: As the other people say, you may also change your plan and do the maths directly on the lists

Answer (score 0):

one other way

```
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    var List = new ListNode(0);
    var head = List;
    var sum = 0;
    var carry = 0;
    while(l1 || l2 || sum) {
        if(l1) {
            sum = sum + l1.val;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        if(l2) {
            sum = sum + l2.val;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        if(sum >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
            sum = sum - 10;
        }
        head.next = new ListNode(sum)
        head = head.next;
        sum = carry;
        carry = 0;
    }
    return List.next;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your plan seems complicated.  Just write enough of an ADT to provide a conversion from the list to an int and add the ints.  The reverse is implemented as it's the easiest way to create the data.

```js
function ListNode(val, next)
{
  this.val = val;
  this.next = next;
}

function listNodeFromInt(val) {
    if (val > 10) {
      return new ListNode(val % 10, listNodeFromInt(Math.trunc(val / 10)));
    }
    return new ListNode(val, null);
}

function intFromNode(node) {
  var foo = 0;
  var exp = 0;
  
  while(node) { foo += node.val * Math.pow(10, exp++); node = node.next }
  return foo
}

var a = listNodeFromInt(342);
console.log(a);
var b = listNodeFromInt(465);
console.log(b);

console.log(listNodeFromInt(intFromNode(a) + intFromNode(b)));
```